# Web Api 2 OkResult not passing generic lists

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api

Using Fiddler to test, the following web api 2 method will return the object with the Success property filled out correctly but the Results property is always empty. Stepping through the debugger there is data in the list but not sent as part of the response.

The objects I'm returning are proxy objects generated by EF which might have something to do with it as well.

```
public class ApiResult<T>
{
    public ApiResult()
    {
        Results = new List<T>();
    }

    public bool Success { get; set; }
    public List<T> Results { get; set; }
}


[HttpGet]
[Route("test")]
public IHttpActionResult test()
{
    ApiResult<User> rv = new ApiResult<User>();
    rv.Success = true;
    rv.Results.Add(new User { name = "Steve" })
    rv.Results.Add(new User { name = "Dave" })

    return Ok(rv);
}
```

JSON Result

```
 {"Success":true,"Results":[{},{}]}
```

WebApiConfig.cs

```
config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();
config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
    name: "DefaultApi",
    routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
    defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are defining the property Results as a list of `object`. Since the type `object` doesn't have any property the serializer return an empty object. Try defining Results as a list of `User` like this:

```
public class ApiResult
{
    public ApiResult()
    {
        Results = new List<User>();
    }

    public bool Success { get; set; }
    public List<User> Results { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: This makes total sense. How would I be able to use this generically to use as a return object for different api calls? This one returns a User object, other may return different domain models.

Comment: You could try to use generic parameters like this `public class ApiResult<T>` and `public List<T> Results`. Then you call `ApiResult<User> rv = new ApiResult<User>();` to get the correct type. See https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0zk36dx2.aspx to get more info on generic parameters.

Comment: I've updated my code and the example above and I'm still producing the same results

Comment: Try to remove the json formatter on the WebApiConfig to see if its him that is causing this problem or not: `config.Formatters.Remove(config.Formatters.JsonFormatter);`.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/126673/discussion-between-vyrira-and-user3953989).

Comment: Adding a generic type to my ApiResult is what did the trick! My other issue is unrelated. The default json serializer cannot serialize EF entities!